# Microsoft Chart Controls runtime chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, controls

I am using microsoft chart controls in VB.net. The graph data currently comes from my database, but all the series and chart formats were made before runtime. I want to know how to make charts on runtime, being able to select the x axis from my dataset and multiple y columns from my dataset. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Made before runtime" is very unclear, I'll assume you used the designer and changed properties in the Property grid window.

In the Solution Explorer window, click the "Show All Files" icon.  That shows a node next to your form, open it and double-click the Designer.vb file.  Scroll down to the InitializeComponent method, you'll see code that was generated by the designer to initialize the chart control.

Copy and paste this code into your own method.  That gives you a major running start on the code you need to configure the chart yourself at runtime.

Comment: All my graphs are graphing, revenue totals last year, projected revenue, revenue this year. However, I want them to have the option to choose which bars are shown

Comment: Yes, my answer will help you figure out how to do this.  Change the properties in the grid to get the different chart you want.  Observe how that changes the code in InitializeComponent().  Keep the MSDN docs handy to understand what the code does.

Comment: A Q&D solution is to create multiple charts and only make one of them visible.

Comment: Creating multiple charts would be a bad way of doing it, but your right looking up the generated code helped